# multiplication of different types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I'm new to haskell, and from time to time I bump into a problem I'll try to describe here in a few words. Imagine, I want to declare different types for different measures so Haskell type system would find errors in my formulas:

```
newtype Dist = Km Float
newtype Time = H Float
newtype Velocity = KmH Float

(/) :: Dist → Time → Velocity
(Km d) / (H t) = KmH (d / v)

(*) :: Velocity → Time → Dist
(KmH v) * (H t) = Km (v * t)
```

so, any time when I try to use wrong units of measures in my formulas the compiler would bite.

The problem is that I can't implement ad-hoc polimorphism like this. With this code I bring ambiguity - the complier can distinguish my operator * and the one defined in Prelude. Declaration of an instance of Num class also is not possible since I need different types in parameters.

I'm wondering how people solve the problem usually.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I once saw an Ada project trying to do it this way, and it went horribly wrong because the type system wasn't up to it.  I suggest you either use Dimensional (which exploits the power of the Haskell type system to do it right) or else stick to type synonyms and rely on code review to catch the defects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to reformulate your unit system a bit. Try something like this:

```
data Unit = Unit String
          | Unit :/: Unit
          | Unit :*: Unit
          | Unit :^: Int
          deriving (Show,Eq)

instance Num Unit where
  -- Insert reasonable definition here
  x * y = ...

data UnitNum n = UN n Unit

instance Num (Num n) => UnitNum n where
  UN n u + Un k u' | u == u' = UN (n+k) u
                   | otherwise = error ...
  -- insert other definitions here.

km,h,kmh :: Unit

km = Unit "km"
h = Unit "h"
kmh = km / h
```

#### Edit:

Something similar to this, but quite different was implemented in the [dimensional](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional) package. Read the sourcecode, it's literate Haskell and quite good to understand. This code should be good enough for most scientific applications.

Comment: Note that this implementation is purely dynamic. The fun part is getting thec ompiler to do the work (as does dimensional)!

Comment: Sorry for nub question. What is `:/:` in `Unit :/: Unit`?

Comment: @Maxym: It,s the type constructor of Unit.

Comment: I've never seen such a construction of Data constructor with an infix function in between two colons. I have a lot to learn in Haskell still. Can you point me to any doc for this?

Comment: This is a GHC extension, each indicted op that starts with a colon is treated ad a data constructor. You can also use this kind of name at type level, eg. :-> is a valid type name in Haskell.

Answer (score 7):

You can hide the usual (*) if you want, by

```
import Prelude hiding((*))
```

Or hide all of Num

```
import Prelude hiding(Num(..))
```

Then you can define your own multiplication, probably along the lines

```
class Mul a b c | a b -> c, b c -> a, c a -> b where
    (*) :: a -> b -> c
```

Comment: Yeah, I also thought about that. I guess in this case everyone who uses my module will have to import prelude hiding something? Can it be automated? Probably not, because for instance `Data.Foldable` module clearly says in its documentation to solve this problem in host module.

Comment: Unfortunately, it can't be automated.  For minimum hassle for the user of your module you need to give the multiplication a different name.

Comment: I understand why you have this `a b -> c` . That says, `c` is determined by `a` and `b`. if so, why do you also have `b c -> a` and  `c a -> b`, given that `(*) :: a -> b -> c`? Please elaborate.

Comment: And why do need to hide `Num` things from `Prelude`? `(*)` from it will interfere with `Mul`? I suppose the correct impl will be resolved by the types.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way is to create a different operator for multiplying your type — plain `*` is already taken. You can define your own operators using any combination of the characters `!#$%&*+./<=>?@\^|-~`. So you could use `|*|` (the TIE Fighter operator) and `|/|` or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

The way I've done this (to avoid the type-level complexity that is the dimensional package) is basically your newtype solution, but with a fair number of helper functions.

```
class Units a where
    wrap :: Double -> a
    unWrap :: a -> Double

instance Units Double where
    wrap = id
    unWrap = id

inWrap :: (Units a) => (Double -> Double) -> a -> a
inWrap f = wrap . f . unWrap

newtype Years = Years Double deriving (Typeable, Show, Eq, Ord)
instance Units Years where
    wrap = Years
    unWrap (Years x) = x

newtype a :/: b = Per a deriving (Typeable, Show, Eq, Ord)
instance Units a => Units (a :/: b) where
    wrap = Per . wrap
    unWrap (Per x) = unWrap x

perYears :: a -> a :/: Years
perYears = Per

class Additive a where
    (+%) :: a -> a -> a
    negU :: a -> a
    (-%) :: a -> a -> a
    x -% y = x +% negU y

instance Units a => Additive a
    where x +% y = wrap $ unWrap x + unWrap y
          negU = inWrap negate

class ScalarMult f where
    (.*) :: f -> Double -> f
class ScalarAdd f where
    (.+) :: f -> Double -> f

instance Units a => ScalarAdd a where
    f .+ v = inWrap (+ v) f
instance Units a => ScalarMult a where
    f .* v = inWrap (* v) f
```

and soforth...